# How can I download a file in Python whose link is hidden behind a Javascript function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download a CSV file provided by the *Download to CSV* link here: https://www.misoenergy.org/planning/generator-interconnection/GI_Queue/gi-interactive-queue/.

The problem is that it is appears to be hidden behind a javascript function and the resulting URL is different each time you click it.

I have tried using `requests.get()` and `urllib.urlretrieve()` but all it gives is the parent page.

How can I get the link behind that button and download the CSV using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use their Ajax API call to download the data in Json form, parse it and save as CSV:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = "https://www.misoenergy.org/api/giqueue/getprojects"

data = requests.get(api_url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(by="projectNumber")
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: How did you identify the API URL in this case?

Comment: @d0m1n0 I opened the Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and refreshed page (In Firefox, Chrome has something similar too). There are all requests the page is doing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try web scraping the link using Beautiful Soup or Scrapy, then use the link to download the csv. What libraries are you using currently?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: You need 50 reputation to comment, I have 9.